# Closure of smooth functions in Besov spaces

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, harmonic-analysis

For real numbers $\alpha > \beta$, we know there is a continuous embedding of Besov spaces $B^\alpha_{\infty,\infty}\subset B^\beta_{\infty,\infty}$. We take the closure of the intersection $C^{\infty} \cap B^\beta_{\infty,\infty}$ in $B^\beta_{\infty,\infty}$, where $C^{\infty}$ is the space of smooth functions, and then intersect this closure with $B^\alpha_{\infty,\infty}$, how can we show that the result is dense in $B^\alpha_{\infty,\infty}$?

Comment: Are the Besov spaces you consider defined on $\mathbb{R}^d$? If not, what kind of domains do you consider?

Comment: @OnurOktay Yes, the domain is $\mathbb{R}^d$

Comment: $B^s_{\infty,\infty}(\mathbb{R}^d)$ are the Hölder-Zygmund spaces. Please see https://mathoverflow.net/questions/244377/density-of-smooth-functions-on-hölder-spaces

Comment: Please also see Hajlasz's reply in https://mathoverflow.net/questions/29869/density-of-smooth-functions-under-h%C3%B6lder-metric

Comment: For the equivalence of $B^s_{\infty,\infty}$ and the Hölder Zygmund spaces $C^s$, please see the monograph by Triebel "Theory of Function Spaces, I", Sections 2.3.5 and 2.5.7